# AngularJS, notify data change from directive to its parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that abstracts a menu. The menu item selection needs to be notified to its parent controller so it can take required action. There are multiple ways I could get this achieved.

1. Pass a scope variable from controller to directive and observe the change on this variable. Within the directive change this variable to indicate the selection option.
2. Pass a callback method from controller to directive. Invoke the callback from directive upon change.
3. Observe the changes in controller using $scope.$on and notify  from the directive using scope.$emit

I could not  clearly arrive at which one option is better. I am leaning towards option 3 as it seems to be cleaner but I am not sure if this has a unwanted coupling. I would like to hear an opinion from others, which solution would favour clear dependency and good for testability.

## UPDATE:

After reading the suggestions and thought, I picked up Option 2 for below reasons:

1. It is very obvious by looking into the HTML about the dependency

   ```
   <menu save="onSave()" filterByDate="filterByDate(date)"></menu>
   ```
2. Unit testing is very explicit and tell about the API (interface) the directive

Comment: Both options 2 and 3 are fine. With option 2 your dependency is explicit.

Comment: I would choose option 2. Option 3 will be fine too, but I don't like event, like Chandermani said, it's way less explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't like using observe\emit\on unless i have too. It isn't always obvious looking at someone elses code where it is being set. This can lead to spaghetti code. If you have a call back, i find the direct link is more obvious to the eye and easier to find. This is in conjunction with well named properties etc. At the end of the day it's a matter of personal\team taste.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a modified version of 1. But instead of passing a variable, inject a service wherever you need.

The service can look something like this:

```
    yourApp.factory('SelectedMenu',
        function () {
            //set a default or just initialize it
            var menuItem = {
                id: 1,
                code:"x"
            };
            return {
                getId: function () { return menuItem.id; },
                getCode: function() { return menuItem.code;},
                setId: function(newId){menuItem.id = newId},
                setCode: function(newCode){menuItem.code=newCode;},
            };
        }
    );
```

In the directive(s) which controlls the behavior  create a watch:

```
    $scope.$watch(
                        function() {
                            //should be idempotent!  can execute multiple times per $digest cycle when a change is detected
                            // (good compromise for not polluting $rootScope)
                            return SelectedMenu.getId();
                        },
                        function( newValue) {
                            //do your thing...
                        }
                    );
```

When you need to use it/update the value you can set the code or any other property you want and finally set the id to trigger the update.

```
SelectedMenu.setId(someones.id);
```

It is the cleanest solution i came across. If you want, you can abstract the usage even more with another service if the data object is more complex.